# What is the correct adjective to describe this situation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose the following scenario.  A person is in line at a store.  Let's call them "subject 1."  In front of them in line is another person.  Let's call them "subject 2."  Along comes a third person who approaches subject 2.  We'll call them "subject 3."  Subject 3 starts calling subject 2 a number of racial pejoratives, then tells subject 2 to "move" and cuts in front of subject 2 in line.  Subject 1 meanwhile does nothing and thinks to himself/herself "not my problem."

Subject 2 is a victim of racism.  Subject 3 is a racist.  But, what is subject 1?  They are not a racist by definition.  They aren't refusing to stick up for subject 2 out of fear.  Subject 1 just doesn't care either way.  I'm looking for the right word to describe the implicit lack of empathy for subject 2.

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241258/single-word-antonym-of-empathy) seems similiar, and was closed for lack of research.

Comment: subject 1 is apathetic.  But is also too timid to complain that subject 3 has cut in front of him.

Comment: On a lighter note, subject 1 was an english usage enthusiast who was preoccupied with framing a question in this forum, to find out a word which describes him best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apathetic... or indifferent, unmoved, unsympathetic, callous, possibly even lackadaisical, self absorbed,self centered, remote, unconcerned.

Depending how the sentence (s) are structured, these are a variety of options!

Hope this helped! :)